# Primefaces BarChart CartesianChartModel X Axis

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart using Primefaces dynamically based on a native SQL query. I'm able to iterate through my list to populate the chart, but the x values aren't showing up correctly.  Here's a hardcoded example:

```
public CartesianChartModel ChartBean() {
    model = new CartesianChartModel();
    ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
    boys.setLabel("Boys");
    boys.set("2004", 120);

    ChartSeries boys2 = new ChartSeries();
    boys2.setLabel("Boys2");

    boys2.set("2005", 100);
    ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();
    girls.setLabel("Girls");
    girls.set("2004", 52);

    ChartSeries girls2 = new ChartSeries();
    girls2.setLabel("Girls2");

    girls2.set("2005", 60);
    model.addSeries(boys);
    model.addSeries(girls);
    model.addSeries(boys2);
    model.addSeries(girls2);
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use? `org.primefaces.model.chart.BarChartModel` for a bar chart?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am using Primefaces 4, but even after updating to 5 and utilizing BarChartModel, the x axis is only showing 2004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this as an answer because it is too lang to be posted as comment. If it does not answer your question please let me know and I will remove this answer..

I did not test it, but I could imagine that the model is expecting "complete series" for each series item. Depending on what you need either try using only two series:

```
ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
boys.setLabel("Boys");
boys.set("2004", 120);
boys.set("2005", 100);

ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();
girls.setLabel("Girls");
girls.set("2004", 52);
girls.set("2005", 60);
```

Or fill up all your series

```
ChartSeries boys = new ChartSeries();
boys.setLabel("Boys");
boys.set("2004", 120);
boys.set("2005", 0);

ChartSeries boys2 = new ChartSeries();
boys2.setLabel("Boys2");
boys2.set("2004", 0);
boys2.set("2005", 100);

ChartSeries girls = new ChartSeries();
girls.setLabel("Girls");
girls.set("2004", 52);
girls.set("2005", 0);

ChartSeries girls2 = new ChartSeries();
girls2.setLabel("Girls2");
girls2.set("2004", 0);
girls2.set("2005", 60);
```

Comment: This corrected the axis issue. I'll now have to figure out how to dynamically set the series values given I won't know them beforehand.

Comment: this highly depends on how your datamodel exactly looks like. But that is another question more related to algorithms in general (and/or maybe sql), not to the primefaces Framework